# How do I make my page to redirect to a page in other project without affecting the session through ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im developing a web app in angular js , I use spring at my backend and ui-router for navigation. Now, here's the problem, I cant seem to move from one project to another through angularjs. Here's my piece of code. I have gotten over '#' in the url to start with, my app.js looks like this  -

```
$stateProvider.state("index",{

url:"/",
controller : "myFeedpanel as feed",
templateUrl: "angular-malkeet updation/Feed/feed.html",

});

$stateProvider.state("search",{

url:"/Search",
controller : "myCtrl as first",
templateUrl: "other_project/profile/abcd.html"
});
```

All of my other pages seem to work, just the one in some other project doesn't work.

So I tried to do this -

```
$stateProvider.state("index",{

url:"/",
controller : "myFeedpanel as feed",
templateUrl: "angular-malkeet updation/Feed/feed.html",

});

$stateProvider.state("search",{

url:"/Search",
controller : "myCtrl as first",
templateUrl: "http://www.artle.in"
});
```

When i looked at my Firefox console - the GET seem to return 200, which means it is accessing the page. But nothing pops up on the screen.

My agenda of moving from one project to other is important to me so that when people sign's up to my webapp , I can redirect them to a Getting started project then to their profile. If there's a neater way to do this without hurting workflows of teams working, I would consider doing it.

Thank you for going through my problem. Really grateful for that.

Comment: What you mean with different project? Is it a diiferent domain? In your first sample it looks like just another folder.

Answer (score 1):

In templateUrl you use url of web page, not a particular template file. It handles only internal page url's.
you can try something like

template: 'Redirecting...window.location="http://www.example.com"'

Comment: So you mean to say i can redirect to another project using window.location ?

Comment: Yes. And use $window in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

It may be html5mode

From the docs

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Relative links

Be sure to check all relative links, images, scripts etc. You must either specify the url base in the head of your main html file () or you must use absolute urls (starting with /) everywhere because relative urls will be resolved to absolute urls using the initial absolute url of the document, which is often different from the root of the application.

Comment: The html5mode is set to true and its working fine, i have managed to get rid of # in the url. For that in my index.html i did base="/" and in app.js i have to give my project name to make it work. Thats not the problem, problem is i wanna move to another project and i dont know how to do that?